# Duplicate key error during Umbraco installation

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm installing Umbraco V7 and get this error during installation

```
Error during installation

The database failed to install. ERROR: The database configuration failed 
with the following message: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because  
a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.cmsPropertyType' and the         
index name 'IX_cmsPropertyTypeUniqueID'. 
The duplicate key value is (00000000-    0000-0000-0000-000000000000).

The statement has been terminated. Please check log file for additional
information (can be found in '/App_Data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt')
```

Any Idea where I can get full DB script for Umbraco or Full DB Backup?

Comment: This is a brand new install, or an update?

Comment: I would drop your db and start install over; or have you already tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a brand new install, I would try wiping your db and starting the install over. It sounds like something got corrupted once, and now it is perpetually breaking.

Comment: Were you able to get through the installation?